# Mysql query to find rows based on other column value using left join

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have a MySQL table temp_employee as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `temp_employee` (
  `employee_id` varchar(22) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `application_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`employee_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

And data in the table as follows:

| employee_id | application_date |
| --- | --- |
| emp.10062808068 | 2023-03-30 07:09:31 |
| emp.10036984442 | 2023-03-30 09:48:30 |
| emp.10041499192 | 2023-03-30 09:58:55 |
| emp.10012314367 | 2023-03-30 03:33:28 |

Insert query for temp_employee table:

```
INSERT INTO `temp_employee` (`employee_id`, `application_date`)
VALUES
    ('emp.10012314367', '2023-03-30 03:33:28'),
    ('emp.10036984442', '2023-03-30 09:48:30'),
    ('emp.10041499192', '2023-03-30 09:58:55'),
    ('emp.10062808068', '2023-03-30 07:09:31');
```

There is another table employee_logs as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `employee_logs` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `employee_id` varchar(22) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `type` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `updated_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

The data in the employee_logs table as follows:

| id | employee_id | type | status | updated_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | emp.10000000001 | 1 | 2 | 2021-04-30 10:19:31 |
| 2 | emp.10000000002 | 2 | 2 | 2022-06-30 17:29:31 |
| 3 | emp.10062808068 | 1 | 2 | 2023-03-30 11:19:20 |
| 4 | emp.10000000003 | 2 | 3 | 2023-03-30 03:03:30 |
| 5 | emp.10000000004 | 1 | 2 | 2023-03-30 04:04:40 |
| 6 | emp.10012314367 | 2 | 1 | 2023-03-30 13:13:31 |
| 7 | emp.10062808068 | 2 | 3 | 2023-03-20 17:24:10 |
| 8 | emp.10036984442 | 1 | 2 | 2023-03-30 09:09:09 |
| 9 | emp.10012314367 | 2 | 1 | 2023-03-20 10:10:10 |
| 10 | emp.10012314367 | 2 | 2 | 2023-03-21 12:12:12 |

Insert query for employee_logs table:

```
INSERT INTO `employee_logs` (`id`, `employee_id`, `type`, `status`, `updated_time`)
VALUES
    (1, 'emp.10000000001', 1, 2, '2021-04-30 10:19:31'),
    (2, 'emp.10000000002', 2, 2, '2022-06-30 17:29:31'),
    (3, 'emp.10062808068', 1, 2, '2023-03-30 11:19:20'),
    (4, 'emp.10000000003', 2, 3, '2023-03-30 03:03:30'),
    (5, 'emp.10000000004', 1, 2, '2023-03-30 04:04:40'),
    (6, 'emp.10012314367', 2, 1, '2023-03-30 13:13:31'),
    (7, 'emp.10062808068', 2, 3, '2023-03-20 17:24:10'),
    (8, 'emp.10036984442', 1, 2, '2023-03-30 09:09:09'),
    (9, 'emp.10012314367', 2, 1, '2023-03-20 10:10:10'),
    (10, 'emp.10012314367', 2, 2, '2023-03-21 12:12:12');
```

I want Mysql query to get type, status & updated_time for each employee_id in temp_employee table which select single row from employee_logs table with condition status != 3 AND updated_time <= application_date.

Expected Result (No. of rows same as the count of temp_employee table)

| employee_id | type | status | updated_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| emp.10062808068 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| emp.10036984442 | 1 | 2 | 2023-03-30 09:09:09 |
| emp.10041499192 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| emp.10012314367 | 2 | 2 | 2023-03-21 12:12:12 |

employee_logs table is huge with more than 40 million rows and can have multiple rows with the same employee_id.

Explanation on the employee_logs table which rows should picked by the condition (status <> 3 AND updated_time <= application_date), as follows:

```
1   emp.10000000001    1       2      2021-04-30 10:19:31 -- should not as emp_id not exists in temp table 
2   emp.10000000002    2       2      2022-06-30 17:29:31 -- should not as emp_id not exists in temp table
3   emp.10062808068    1       2      2023-03-30 11:19:20 -- should not return as updated_time > application_date 2023-03-30 07:09:31
4   emp.10000000003    2       3      2023-03-30 03:03:30 -- should not as emp_id not exists in temp table
5   emp.10000000004    1       2      2023-03-30 04:04:40 -- should not as emp_id not exists in temp table
6   emp.10012314367    2       1      2023-03-30 13:13:31 -- should not return as updated_time > application_date 2023-03-30 03:33:28
7   emp.10062808068    2       3      2023-03-20 17:24:10 -- should not return as status = 3
8   emp.10036984442    1       2      2023-03-30 09:09:09 -- should return as updated_time <= application_date && status != 3 
9   emp.10012314367    2       1      2023-03-20 10:10:10 -- should not return as updated_time < application_date 2023-03-30 03:33:28 but not latest
10  emp.10012314367    2       2      2023-03-21 12:12:12 -- should return as updated_time < application_date 2023-03-30 03:33:28
```

Any help in the query to achieve the desired output will be highly appreciated. TIA

Comment: Why does emp.10062808068 NULL NULL NULL appear in your expected result when both entries in the explanation say should not return?

Comment: @P.Salmon There are 2 rows in logs table with id=3, where updated_time > application_date and id=7, here status = 3, since no match found then type, status & updated_time should be NULL[For not found case]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query worked for me, the application_date column value in the temp_employee table was incorrect, after the fix the query return expected result.

```
SELECT t.employee_id, oel.type, oel.status, oel.updated_time
FROM (
    SELECT t.employee_id, MAX(el.updated_time) updated_time
    FROM temp_employee t LEFT JOIN employee_logs el
        ON t.employee_id = el.employee_id 
        AND el.status <> 3 
        AND el.updated_time <= t.application_date
    GROUP BY t.employee_id
) t LEFT JOIN employee_logs oel
ON t.employee_id = oel.employee_id AND t.updated_time = oel.updated_time;
```

SQL Fiddle link [solution](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/04f08a7/1)

Comment: Good to see .... :)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired output by modifying your query to use a subquery with a conditional aggregation to select the appropriate rows from the employee_logs table. Here's the query to get the type, status, and updated_time for each employee_id in the temp_employee table based on your conditions:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e73ea8/6

```
    SELECT
    te.employee_id,
    CASE WHEN el.status IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE el.type END AS type,
    CASE WHEN el.status IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE el.status END AS status,
    CASE WHEN el.status IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE el.updated_time END AS updated_time
FROM temp_employee te
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        el.employee_id,
        MAX(CASE WHEN el.status != 3 AND el.updated_time <= te.application_date THEN el.updated_time ELSE NULL END) AS updated_time,
        MAX(CASE WHEN el.status != 3 AND el.updated_time <= te.application_date THEN el.type ELSE NULL END) AS type,
        MAX(CASE WHEN el.status != 3 AND el.updated_time <= te.application_date THEN el.status ELSE NULL END) AS status
    FROM employee_logs el
    JOIN temp_employee te ON el.employee_id = te.employee_id
    GROUP BY el.employee_id, te.application_date
) el ON te.employee_id = el.employee_id;
```

Let me provide you the another version of the query

```
SELECT
    te.employee_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN el.status != 3 AND el.updated_time <= te.application_date THEN el.type END) AS type,
    MAX(CASE WHEN el.status != 3 AND el.updated_time <= te.application_date THEN el.status END) AS status,
    MAX(CASE WHEN el.status != 3 AND el.updated_time <= te.application_date THEN el.updated_time END) AS updated_time
FROM temp_employee te
LEFT JOIN employee_logs el
    ON te.employee_id = el.employee_id
GROUP BY te.employee_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The above query returned the desired result, but I'm not sure about its performance.

Comment: @Anothercoder 
 I have edited the answer and optimized the query..

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is a temporary required query, to check if employees have agreed to some changes published (or sth. the like)

So, performance shouldn't be all to critical.

As a first step, I would use this query to determine the `most recent` status values per employee. Join the `emp_log` table on itself, with condition `L.emp_id = R.emp_id and L.update_date < R.update_date` - and pick the results, where the right set is `null` (means, there is no further record with a more recent update-state for this employee):

```
SELECT 
  L.employee_id,
  L.type,
  L.status,
  L.updated_time
FROM 
  employee_logs L
LEFT JOIN 
  employee_logs R
on
  L.employee_id = R.employee_id AND
  L.updated_time < R.updated_time
WHERE
  isnull(R.updated_time)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a95da/2

Now, you got the most recent updates - just missing the employees that have no updates -> right join them in.

```
SELECT 
   ifnull(temp.employee_id, e.employee_id) as employee_id,
   temp.type,
   temp.status,
   temp.updated_time,
   e.application_date
 FROM 
(SELECT 
      L.employee_id,
      L.type,
      L.status,
      L.updated_time
    FROM 
      employee_logs L
    LEFT JOIN 
      employee_logs R
    on
      L.employee_id = R.employee_id AND
      L.updated_time < R.updated_time
    WHERE
      isnull(R.updated_time)
    ) as temp
    RIGHT JOIN
      employees e
    ON 
      temp.employee_id = e.employee_id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a95da/10

On the final result, you can apply your where-conditions as required. (`WHERE temp.status <> 3 and temp.update_time <= e.application_date)` - I left this out, cause it doesn't make sence to me, that there are update-times BEFORE the employee even applied...

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the above query also doesn't return the desired result, Above query return data for "emp.10062808068" and incorrect data for "emp.10012314367" FYI I have added the insert query for both the tables.

Comment: @Anothercoder youve read the (last) line, that I left out the conditions?

Comment: employees table is not actual employee table, and application_date is not the employee created date, here what I want to achieve is to check the type and status of the employee from employee_logs table just before a specific event.
And adding condition`WHERE temp.status <> 3 AND temp.updated_time <= e.application_date;` at last returns no row.